# Maximum rate of change for a data

Tags: calculus

I came up with a question when studying calculus. Suppose that we have a data set, say $v=v(t)$. Assume that we know about their physical meaning and consequently we know that function $V$ fits the data well. Now the maximum rate of change of the data is better approximated by:

a) maximum rate of change of $V$

b) average rate of change of $V$

c) we cannot say

I think (b) gives a more reasonable value. But is there a reasoning behind that? or other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your $V(t)$ is a "well fit" to $v(t)$, I would expect that I can use $V$ instead of $v$ for certain computations. This would imply answer a).

The details however are hidden in the "well fit" statement, we have no information on the relationship between $V$ and $v$ beyond that, so
the rational statement is answer c), we cannot say, we need more information.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of good approximation to the data, $\frac{dV}{dt}$ is *not* the same as a good approximation to the derivative of the data. As an example, consider that your model $V$ may be a Fourier series. In general, the derivative of your data is going to be *less* smooth than the original data so it will take *more* terms to get a good approximation for the derivative than it took to get a good representation of the original data. So, if you want to look at the maximum rate of change within your data set, I would prefer a method that approximates the derivative directly and looks at the maximum of that.